# Systemd service wait wifi adapter to plug in

Tags: linux, debian, systemd-unit

I have a systemd service that change MAC address every boot to wifi adapter. Systemd service works fine. I want this systemd service **not wait 1m 30sec** when the wifi adapter is not plug in the usb. I don't want to trigger systemd service **via udev rules** because systemd service starts after network-pre.target and NetworkManager.service, I want systemd service **to start before those services**.

How can I do that?

```
[Unit]
Description=macchanger on %I
Wants=network-pre.target
Before=network-pre.target
BindsTo=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/macchanger -r %I
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: If this is just randomization, networkManager already includes that functionality. Other than that, you're explicitly listing this unit as dependency of your target and to be run before network-pre. So, these would be the first things I'd change

Comment: Since you want your service to run before network setup, you might need `DefaultDependencies=no`, because otherwise you'll get an implicit `After=sysinit.target basic.target` which might cause a dependency conflict.

Comment: Easiest way: pull the service with the device unit (i.e., change the `WantedBy=` to the device unit and perform a disable/enable cycle).

Comment: @telcoM telcoM It doesn't work your setup. Systemd wait 1m 30 second to plug usb wifi adapter.

Comment: @TomYan Tom what do you mean? What I have to put after WantedBy= ? Please show me an example.

Comment: I meant that `DefaultDependences=no` might be necessary; however, it alone might not be a sufficient fix. That's why I wrote it as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: `sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device`

Comment: @telcoM I used your setup in the past. It doesn't work.

Comment: @TomYan With your setup `systemd service` starts after `network-pre.target and NetworkManager.service`

Comment: Well, if you need NM to wait for your service / the device unit, then you'll have to pull it with them, which means NM will either always wait for the device, or it will only start if/when the device shows up. It isn't logically possible for it to "wait if it will show up", because there's no way for systemd to tell whether the device is just not detected yet or whether it just won't be there. If you can't accept NM to start "optionally", then you should really drop the approach (but see how NM can randomize the MAC for you).

Comment: But of course, you can instead override the timeout to something really short, but not too short ;-)

Comment: @TomYan How can I reduce time to systemd service from 1m 30 sec to 10 seconds?